# Can I trigger Zeppelin to run a particular block within a command?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I'd like to rerun a notebook and have different blocks run the first time vs the second time.

I don't want to have one really large block that has all of the code. I'd like to keep them as blocks so that the commands only runs one piece at a time, and I can see how far it got.

We run Zeppelin on Hadoop with Apache Spark.

Can I cause the interpreter to run particular blocks as part of a user defined function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`z.run(<paragrah_id>)`**

**`Example:`**

In the below screenshot we are running **2** paragrah and it prints **`sc2`**.

[image]

Comment: This is literally awesome

Comment: @Cauder, Paragrahids are sequential numbers starting from `0 to n`,  in the above screenshot we have 3 paragraph's i.e `0,1,2`.

Comment: Some of my notebooks have lots of paragraphs. Is there a command I can run to get the id for a given paragraph?

Comment: Try with **`z.getInterpreterContext().getParagraphId()`** Here is the jira ticket addressing.. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-1772